# OAuth 2, couldn't one use better names for the "access_token" and the "authentication code"?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to understand OAuth 2:

As I understand it "access_token" and "authentication code" are really quite similar in that they represent the end-users will. The only difference is that the access_token can be used alone while the "authentication code" must be used with the app_secret (client_secret in rfc6749).

So in my mind it would clarify a lot, if they had similar names, like:

- "full_token", "strong_token" or "super_token" for "access_token" as it can be used alone. It is really powerful, it must never be transferred over a non secure line. (But can be used to make requests directly from the browser)
- "half_token", "weak_token" or "normal_token" for "authentication code" because it must be combined with the app_secret. It can be transferred over non secure lines, but as the app_secret never should be sent to the browser, it can never be used from there.

And as a consequence the corresponding grant type names would be called:

- "full_token grant type" for "implicit grant type"

  - The term means that a full_token is generated directly and returned to the browser only, (since it is returned in the fragment of the redirect uri (the #-part of the uri) which is not included when the browser makes the redirect request (so it will never be exposed even if the request is to a non-secure uri)). The browser can then use it to extract data, or it can be transferred to the app server (if the app uses TLS)
- "half_token grant type" for "authorization code grant type"

  - The term means that a half_token is generated, the app makes sure it comes to the app server (secure line *not* needed). At the app server it is sent along with the app_secret to extract data from the authorization server. (rfc6749 suggests that it should first be replaced with a full_token, but this shouldn't be necessary in my mind.)

Or are there other differences that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization code is less like an access token than your summary implies. In particular, this is not accurate: "The only difference is that the access_token can be used alone while the "authentication code" must be used with the app_secret".

In OAuth 2.0 *getting* authorization and *using* authorization are very different, involving different actors with different kinds of information available to them. The authorization code is part of a handshaking process with the *authorization server* to get permission to access a protected resource. The resulting access token is then sent to the *resource server* (which does not need to know any client secrets or other credentials) to access the resource on behalf of a user.

So they are actually quite different.

Comment: Ah, so if the authorization server and the resource server were the same, it could be right to view it as I did?!

Answer (score 0):

your theory of

> full_token, half_token, strong_token, super_token

exists because you misunderstood the `Access_token` and `Authorization_code`.

`Authorization_code` is a short lived token which is exchanged to get `Access_token`. Authorization server generate the Authorization_code and send back to the client to keep resource owner's credentials secret. client later exchange this Authorization_code for access token. Once you get the access_token the authorization code get expired and you can not issue another access_token for same Authorization_code.

To access your APIs you pass access_token in header with every request. you cant access your APIs with Authorization_code. That's why Authorization_code is not a `half_token`.

Similarly `full_token, strong_token, super_token` also doesn't make sense as we have only one access_token.

see [Life cycle of Authorization code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584030/oauth-2-0-life-cycle-of-code-in-authorization-code-grant)